# Multiple for loop handling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, for-loop, break

"I am using two for loop one inside another.In the Innermost loop i am checking a 'if condition ' if condition will satisfy, the whole loop i mean both inner loop and outer loop should be stopped.But at the moment the below code can only stop the inner loop outer loop is not stopping.please give me solution."

```
for(int i=0; i<a_AllClothing.count;i++)
            {

                for (int j=0; j<tempAsset_array.count; j++) {

                    if([l_dressName rangeOfString:ImageName].location!=NSNotFound)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Matched");

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you 1st sem CS student? You should read "Let us C" or even +2 level Computer Science book. Use `condtion(s)` in outer loop, also you have the power of `goto, but don't use this frequently.

Comment: Sir i just wanted to know if there has any different technique rather than using a boolean value.

Comment: In java you have labeled loop, in C / Obj-C you need to use `BOOL` or refactor your entire code to a method and in the innermost `if` you can use `return`.

Comment: Using `goto` to break out of a loop is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same with enumerationBlocks. This assumes that you have an array of arrays.

```
__block BOOL containsDress = NO;
[a_AllClothing enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSArray * clothes, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *firstStop) {
    [clothes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * cloth, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *seconStop) {
        if ([cloth isEqualToString:l_dressName]) {
            *firstStop = YES;
            *seconStop = YES;
            containsDress = YES;
        }
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL isFound = NO;
for(int i=0; i<a_AllClothing.count && !isFound;i++)
            {

                for (int j=0; j<tempAsset_array.count; j++) {

                    if([l_dressName rangeOfString:ImageName].location!=NSNotFound)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Matched");
                        isFound = YES;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: are you sure ? read code again.

Comment: Read this one wrong as well.  Anyhow, it's still nothing more than a code dump, not an answer